# How come bootstrap text color class is not working for me?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been using bootstrap for a little while. I am having trouble with the text-white class. It is not changing the text color. I have provided the code below. What is the problem with what I have here?

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="one">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-white">Example</h1>
    <p class="text-white">Second Example</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that using `text-white` is not compatible with bootstrap 3. When I changed to bootstrap 4 it worked.

The issue if doing this is that other things may not work after the change so be warned that things might break.